# Get Flicker Photo URL

Tags: angularjs, flickr

I am working on Flicker API, using AngularJS for displaying images. I need photo URL on click of image, but my problem is that I am getting a Flicker URL instead of what is required.

> Flickr URL ->
>   http://www.flickr.com/photos/53067560@N00/2658147888/in/set-72157606175084388/
>   Static image URL ->
>   http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3221/2658147888%5F826edc8465.jpg

... and the code used for this is:

```
<div ng-controller="FlickrController">
    <a ng-repeat="photo in photos.items" href="{{ photo.link}}" target="_blank">
        <img ng-src="{{ photo.media.m}}" alt="{{ photo.title}}"
        ng-click="getURL(photo.link)"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Does anyone know about any photo property used for this solution?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html ?

Comment: @JoseM I already gone through this link but doesn't got any solution..

Comment: Which part of the Flicker API are you using exactly?  Can you give us a link to the webpage for the same *exact* api that you call? What is the complete response that you get?

Comment: are you saying you need the static image url (not the flickr url) when you click on the image. If so, you should show FlickrController code